# systemd: limit the number of times a service can restart

Tags: systemd

I'd like to limit the number of times my service can restart, ever. There are burst limits

```
StartLimitIntervalSec=60
StartLimitBurst=5
```

But they limit how many times a service can restart within the specified interval.
Is there any way to specify how many times can a service restart in general? As if the interval was set to infinity.

```
systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2)
```

Comment: Which section of the service (Service or Unit) did you put these in? Also, what's the version of your `systemd`?

Comment: @systrigger I've added the version. Any place in service file that will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Partial solution. I basically set these values

```
StartLimitIntervalSec=1d
StartLimitBurst=5
```

Which limits 5 restarts per day.